# Setting a graph gradient based on 0% red - 100% green

Tags: reactjs, math

I hope I can explain this well enough so here goes.
I have some code like [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-bash-lgxyj?file=/src/index.js:398-461)
You can see the graph is red and green. It shows lows and highs relative to it's own numbers and not necessarily based on negative and positive, so...

The `<stop offset=""` control the gradient position. I've worked out 0% - 100% is perfectly even gradient red to green, 80% - 100% makes it red with the last 20% green and 0% - 20% makes it primarily green to 20% lower half red. (See images below)

So as you can see the `0 - 20%` graph works best in the examples but won't work if someone take's a steep dive from $0 to - $100.

I can return the highest ($72) and lowest (-$10) values in the graph but I don't know how to translate that into the gradient offset percentages.

God I hope I explained that properly.

---

[image]

`0 - 100%`

---

[image]

`0 - 20%`

---

[image]

`80% - 100%`

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something pretty good

First work out whether the majority is green or red by comparing the positive numbers. Then get the percentage of the smaller number in the bigger one and set the offsets to those numbers.

```
var diff = 0
var stopOffsetRed = '0%'
var stopOffsetGreen = '100%'
if (this.state.largestAmountWon > Math.abs(this.state.smallestAmountWon)) {
  diff = (Math.abs(this.state.smallestAmountWon) / this.state.largestAmountWon) * 100
  stopOffsetRed = '0%'
  stopOffsetGreen = diff.toFixed(2) + '100%'
} else {
  diff = 100 - (this.state.largestAmountWon / Math.abs(this.state.smallestAmountWon)) * 100
  stopOffsetRed = diff + '%'
  stopOffsetGreen = '100%'
}
```

Results
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer would greatly benefit from an image with resulting graphs!